# How to enable password for users sending emails to it self?

Tags: postfix, telnet

All emails users require password but if i login with telnet to port 25, i can send a email without password if the from and to are from a list of valid emails accounts. Can anyone tell me how to prevent this and force also in this case the password usage? Thank you

Comment: Does this server also accept email from the Internet?  You understand that email coming from the Internet is not going to have your passwords right?  BTW, I assume you have already performed a Google search for 'postfix require authentication to send', and read the results?  If not, do that now.  If you have, then update your question with more details about why you were not able to follow the guides that show up.

Comment: there are many aspects of Postfix that relate to controlling access: who can connect, who can relay, etc.  Does this help?  http://www.postfix.org/SMTPD_ACCESS_README.html

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean the you can send from one `internal` user to another `internal` user? If so then you need to read up on SMTP as that is how it works. Your server accepts inbound emails for email addresses of domains that your server is authoritative for. That's how your users receive email from the outside world. You could use any from address, that doesn't have any bearing on what you're describing. You are confusing that with authenticated relaying, which is not what is happening when you send email via telnet to an `internal` user.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to setup SMTP authentication for this purpose. By default, SMTP authentication is setup in "Bypass" mode when emails are exchanged internally in the server - depending on your mail server, there would be a setting to enforce SMTP authentication for *All* emails. Can you let us know what mail server are you using so that you can receive appropriate assistance on this?